Why does PolSpice show this message during instalation procedure?
I am having some troubles with the instalations of PolSpice for two different versions, and for my conda enviroment py_cmb. I have been following the steps  by https://www.zonca.dev/posts/2020-10-14-install-healpix-polspice-conda-nersc.html. Once I have installed Healpix_3.70 and cfitsio libraries, the procedure coudn't continue when I tried to run bash run.sh file. Then, the shell shows me the following message:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:164 (message):
HEALPix library not found in /lib/*
Use the  cmake flags  
 -DHEALPIX=/correct/path/to/healpix/top/directory  (and -DSUFFIX=suffix)
  to use {HEALPIX}/lib{SUFFIX}/* and {HEALPIX}/include{SUFFIX}/*  instead
 or
 -DHEALPIX_LIB=/correct/path/to/healpix/library/directory      and
 -DHEALPIX_INCLUDE=/correct/path/to/healpix/include/directory
  to use {HEALPIX_LIB}/* and {HEALPIX_INCLUDE}/*
For more information see the file INSTALL

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
I have followed the message's instructions, but the problem continues.
How should I solve this problem?
I was trying to unistall and re-install healpix and corroborating that the message's libraries are well instaled. I have also been trying to carry out the manual procedure with make. I don't really what are the problems with installation.
Thank you.
